# MAMP 6 - PHP Files being downloaded on a clean install

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I don't know what I did, but MAMP just started to download any PHP file I try to access.[image]

So after a good amount of trying to debug, I just decided to do a clean slate. So I uninstalled MAMP 5, and installed MAMP 6 (With the Pro Trial)

So now with a clean slate, I still get the bug. http files seems to run fine.
Right now I'm working on a WP site, and the downloaded file is the index.php at the root of WP.

So what could be forcing MAMP to download files instead of executing PHP?

Comment: Sure its not your htaccess file?

Comment: the htaccess file at the root of this site in particular is the basic WP one.